# kill a process in windows python 2.5

Tags: python, windows, process, kill

How do i kill a process in windows (xp 32 bits) in python 2.5? 
Someone on stackoverlow posted on how to import ctypes and do it but I don't have a ctypes module.

I am running the process in the following way-

```
ex=Execution(cmd)
#do something
ex.proc.kill()
```

This gives me an error saying Popen object has no attribute kill.
Using os.kill(ex.pid, signal.SIGKILL) gives a similar error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among others, I found two ways:

- http://metazin.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/how-to-kill-a-process-in-windows-using-python/
- https://blogs.oracle.com/rajkumar/entry/how_to_kill_a_process

The latter uses the `subprocess` module in conjunction with `taskkill`. The former `win32api.TerminateProcess`.

Comment: @AlexOkrushko, thanks, it was an old Sun link, edited to link to the hopefully same content on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Popen.kill() is only available after Python 2.6. For 2.5 and earlier, you can use taskkill or the win32api as mentioned by "The MYYN".